# When run django server then facing traceback like TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases

Tags: python, django

**I have upgrade django 1.5 to 1.6 version, due to this reason i am facing this kind of traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
        self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 67, in __call__
        return self.application(environ, start_response)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 187, in __call__
        self.load_middleware()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 49, in load_middleware
        mw_instance = mw_class()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/middleware/locale.py", line 24, in __init__
        for url_pattern in get_resolver(None).url_patterns:
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 346, in url_patterns
        patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 341, in urlconf_module
        self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
        __import__(name)
      File "/home/hsa/Documents/Django/juicypebble/juicypebble/urls.py", line 6, in <module>
        admin.autodiscover()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 29, in autodiscover
        import_module('%s.admin' % app)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
        __import__(name)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cms/admin/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
        import pageadmin
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cms/admin/pageadmin.py", line 30, in <module>
        from cms.admin.change_list import CMSChangeList
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cms/admin/change_list.py", line 7, in <module>
        from cms.utils.permissions import get_user_sites_queryset
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cms/utils/permissions.py", line 4, in <module>
        from cms.plugin_pool import plugin_pool
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cms/plugin_pool.py", line 3, in <module>
        from cms.plugin_base import CMSPluginBase
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cms/plugin_base.py", line 85, in <module>
        class CMSPluginBase(admin.ModelAdmin):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cms/plugin_base.py", line 30, in __new__
        return super_new(cls, name, bases, attrs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/widgets.py", line 137, in __new__
        attrs)
    TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
        metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
    [07/Apr/2014 07:01:32] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 59
```

Comment: Please provide the code that is causing this error.

Comment: I am guessing that the code in /home/hsa/Documents/Django/juicypebble/juicypebble/urls.py line6 might not compatible with Django 1.6. I don't know what juicypebble is :)